# Text formatting in the "Help Text" section

Tags: 7

I'm wondering where the formatting is set for the "Help Text" section. I was thinking that maybe it was plain text, but it does not appear to be so - I want to use the module Collapse Text to collapse the text and make the help text available to the user only if they want to view it, while filling out their registration form.

Is there a way to do this, or will I have to write a third party module?

This is the module I want to use with the help text.

https://drupal.org/project/collapse_text

Comment: That module will not do what you are looking for, it is only for text that you enter into text boxes when editing content.  You could use a couple lines of jQuery to expand/collapse the help box with .slideToggle() or something similar

Comment: Well how is text formatting set for the help fields?

I will probably just write jQuery for it though yes.

Answer (score 0):

The [Advanced Help](https://www.drupal.org/project/advanced_help) module will let you create help texts that can be tied to a help icon on any page, form or form item. Clicking the icon will pop-up a Ajax window with the text.